# Optimize slow query when multiple JOIN LATERAL are present

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance, lateral-join

This is a follow-up optimization on [Adding a SUM group by into a COUNT DISTINCT query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69960090/471313) (albeit with some optimizations and joins simplifications).

I wonder if it's possible to optimize the following **PostgreSQL 13.1** query which took `130322.2ms` to complete. Normally if only one `JOIN LATERAL` is present it does it in a few ms.

What I'm most lost is given that each `JOIN LATERAL` has an `ON` with a condition based on the score of its own subquery, how could I optimize the query potentially reducing the number of `JOIN LATERAL` and still get the same results.

From what I see, it seems it gets slow when conditional `OR` are added to some of the WHERE inside the `JOIN LATERAL` instead of `AND`. See:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM subscriptions q
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        AND ts.tag_id = 21
    ) AS q62958 ON q62958.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        OR ts.tag_id = 32
    ) AS q120342 ON q120342.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        OR ts.tag_id = 35
    ) AS q992506 ON q992506.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        OR ts.tag_id = 33
    ) AS q343255 ON q343255.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        OR ts.tag_id = 29
    ) AS q532052 ON q532052.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        OR ts.tag_id = 30
    ) AS q268437 ON q268437.sum_score <= 1
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        AND ts.tag_id = 46
    ) AS q553964 ON q553964.sum_score >= 3
JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        SUM(ts.score) AS sum_score
      FROM
        quiz_answers qa
        JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id
        JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
      WHERE
        qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
        AND ts.tag_id = 24
    ) AS q928243 ON q928243.sum_score >= 2
WHERE
  q.state = 'subscribed' AND q.app_id = 4
;
```

The `subscriptions` table has less than 15000 rows and less than 2000 matching the `WHERE` clause. Both `q.state` and `q.app_id` have indexes.

The complete `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Ok0h

Comment: For performance questions, we need some basic details. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Crucially important: How many rows in table `subscriptions` and roughly how selective is the filter `WHERE q.state = 'subscribed' AND q.app_id = 4`?

Comment: Please see updated question with updated query and link to EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what you believe `WHERE qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id OR ts.tag_id = ?` is doing. Without the data, schema, or a description of what it's meant to be doing, this just looks wonky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue is that the query is wrong:

```sql
 WHERE
            qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
            OR ts.tag_id = 32
```

The `OR` is misplaced here and must be introduced ***after*** aggregating the right rows. This `WHERE` clause includes all rows with *either* a matching `quiz_id` *or* `tag_id = 32`. So *all* rows, which is nonsense.

In addition to that, you can conflate multiple `LATERAL` subqueries with conditional aggregates like this:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   subscriptions q
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 21) AS sum_score21
        , sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 32) AS sum_score32
        , sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 35) AS sum_score35
     -- , more?
   FROM   quiz_answers qa
   JOIN   answers      a  ON a.id = qa.answer_id
   JOIN   tag_scores   ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
   WHERE  qa.quiz_id = q.quiz_id
   AND    ts.tag_id IN (21, 32, 35) -- more?
   ) AS t ON t.sum_score21 <= 1
          OR t.sum_score32 <= 1
          OR t.sum_score35 <= 1
       -- AND / OR more?
WHERE  q.state = 'subscribed'
AND    q.app_id = 4;
```

Be aware of [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) when adding more conditions with `AND` or `OR`: You may need parentheses as `AND` binds before `OR`.

About aggregated `FILTER`:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

A multicolumn index on `subscriptions(app_id, state, quizz_id)` might help (give you index-only scans). But since the table isn't that big, that's not important.

`LATERAL` (rather than a plain subquery) still makes sense while the outer filter eliminates most rows from table `subscriptions`. A multicolumn index on `tag_scores(answer_id, tag_id)` might help.

With more tags in the subquery and/or more subscriptions, the `LATERAL` variant and the usefulness of said index fall off.

For comparison, here is a variant with plain subquery:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   subscriptions q
JOIN  (
   SELECT qa.quiz_id
        , sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 21) AS sum_score21
        , sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 32) AS sum_score32
        , sum(ts.score) FILTER (WHERE ts.tag_id = 35) AS sum_score35
     -- , more?
   FROM   quiz_answers qa
   JOIN   answers      a  ON a.id = qa.answer_id
   JOIN   tag_scores   ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
   WHERE  ts.tag_id IN (21, 32, 35) -- more?
   GROUP  BY qa.quiz_id
   ) AS t USING (quiz_id)
WHERE  q.state = 'subscribed'
AND    q.app_id = 4
AND   (t.sum_score21 <= 1
    OR t.sum_score32 <= 1
    OR t.sum_score35 <= 1)
    -- AND / OR more?
;
```

Either way, `t.sum_score21 <= 1` qualifies if ...

- at least one row with tag 21 is associated
- and the summed score of all with tag 21 for the same quiz is <= 1

Seems like a pretty narrow filter.

#### Denoise:

If the row in `answers` is never missing (referential integrity enforced with FK constraints?), you can cut out the middleman here:

```sql
   FROM   quiz_answers qa
   JOIN   answers      a  ON a.id = qa.answer_id
   JOIN   tag_scores   ts ON ts.answer_id = a.id
```

-->

```sql
   FROM   quiz_answers qa
   JOIN   tag_scores   ts USING (answer_id)
```

Comment: In that form it doesn't even need to be a lateral join. Just a plain inline-view / sub-query, grouped (and subsequently joined) by quiz_id.  (But, I'm not sure this is what the OP wants, the question is lacking far too many details to be at all confident.)

Comment: @MatBailie: Yep, it doesn't *need* to be. But - like noted above - while most rows of the main table are excluded early on (with the outer filter `WHERE q.state = 'subscribed' AND    q.app_id = 4` LATERAL still makes sense, because the subquery can skip most quizzes this way. The OP might compare both and report the resulting performance to enlighten us ...

Comment: I added an alternative with plain subquery for comparison.

Comment: by the way, I don't see the added value of the `JOIN answers a ON a.id = qa.answer_id` ? Could be removed and just keep `FROM quiz_answers qa JOIN tag_scores ts ON ts.answer_id = qa.answer_id` ?

Comment: If you are interesting in the differences in performance: using `LATERAL` (https://explain.depesz.com/s/rAp2) took `57.308 ms` and using subquery (https://explain.depesz.com/s/PMzI) took `46.549 ms`.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the feedback. Consider the added notes. With more rows being selected in the subquery, the `LATERAL` variant falls off.

Comment: @EdouardH.: Spot on. I added a note accordingly.